# An inequality of semi positive-definite matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $P,Q$ be $n\times n$ semi positive-definite matrices, $P+Q=R$.Show that $|PQ|\leq 1/\sqrt{2} |R|^2$. Here $|P|^2=trace(P^TP)$.

My idea is as follows. Since $P$ is a semi positive-definite matrix, there exists a nonsingular matrix $P_1$ such that $P=P_1^{-1}diag(p_1,\cdots,p_n)P_1$. And what we need is to show the inequality with $P$ replaced by $diag(p_1,\cdots,p_n)$. Precsily,
$$\sum_{i,j}p_i^2q_{ij}^2\leq \frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i,j}(p_i\delta_{ij}+q_{ij})^2]^2.$$
Here $\delta_{ij}$ is the Dirac symbol.

This troubles me, since we do not known $q_{ij}\geq 0$.

Comment: Could you explain what $|PQ|$ means? and why $1/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @M.T A norm...Frobenius norm as well-known.

Comment: Does it mean $|PQ|=\text{Tr}(P^{T}Q)$?

Comment: @M.T a squat needed.

Comment: Could you explain what "a squat needed" means ? Sorry, by as I am not a native English speaker, I try to improve my level, but I have still sometimes a hard time with certain expressions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By manipulation, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}(R^{T}R) = \text{Tr}((P+Q)^{T}(P+Q)) = \text{Tr}(P^{T}P)+\text{Tr}(Q^TQ) + \text{Tr}(P^{T}Q)+\text{Tr}(Q^{T}P).
\end{equation}
Since $\text{Tr}(P^{T}Q) = \text{Tr}(Q^{T}P)$,
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}(R^{T}R) - 4\text{Tr}(P^{T}Q) = \text{Tr}((P-Q)^{T}(P-Q))\geq 0.
\end{equation}
I guess we are done.

Comment: [+1] You use a version of the polarization identity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) which generalizes the algebraic identity $(a+b)^2-4ab=(a-b)^2$ for to vector spaces with inner products.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for reminding.